# Comparing two 4 digit integers, digit by digit

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, int, compare

I am having trouble with a program I'm writing. It is supposed to be a kind of guessing game.
the program will create a random 4 digit number with digits that do not repeat anywhere.
then the user will be asked to input a 4 digit number. the program will then compare this number to the random one it made. for ever digit that is the same and in the correct position it will make a variable (lets just say A) increase by one (1A, 2A, 3A...). for every number that is correct but in the wrong position, it will increase another variable (lets say B) in the same way. The user will get 5 tries to guess correctly with the two variable from before printed after each incorrect answer.

I decided to store the both numbers in an int array and try to compare them that way (moving along each element of the array and checking for a match) right now I am having trouble getting the 2 numbers into arrays. one prints out [1, 2, 3, 4] while the users guess prints out [1 2 3 4] I'm not sure if this will make a difference but I can't seem to figure out why.

Also I am not sure if this is the simplest way to compare two numbers, nor do I really know how to if I got them into arrays. Maybe if statements like this? Some guidence would be really helpful.

```
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    if (random[0] == guess[0]){
    x+1; }
    else if (random[0] == guess[1] || random[0] == guess[2] || random[0] == guess[3])
    y+1;
```

here is what I have so far, I was trying to split the string from the user and store it as an int but it say "Cannot invoke intAt(int) on the primitive type int"

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create scanner object
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // give user the game rules
        System.out.println("The computer has chosen a unique 4 digit number (No digits in the number repeat)\n"
                        + "Each time you guess incorectly you will get a hint. You must guess the number correctly in 5 tries or fewer to win.\n");

        // ask user for their guess
        System.out.println("Please enter your guess: ");

        // read the user input and store it in a string
        int input = keyboard.nextInt();

        int[] guess1 = new int[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            guess1[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(input.intAt(i)));
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(guess1));

    }

    public static int[] numberGenerator(int[] args) {

        // random number generator
        Random randy = new Random();

        // integer array with 4 positions (for each digit)
        int[] randArray = new int[4];

        // creates a variable for each position in the array
        int rand0 = 0;
        int rand1 = 0;
        int rand2 = 0;
        int rand3 = 0;

        // assigns a random value to temporary variable
        int a = randy.nextInt(9);
        int b = randy.nextInt(9);
        int c = randy.nextInt(9);
        int d = randy.nextInt(9);

        // tests to make sure there are no repeating digits in the number
        rand0 = a;

        if (b == a) {
            b = randy.nextInt(9);
        } else
            rand1 = b;

        if (c == a || c == b) {
            c = randy.nextInt(9);
        } else
            rand2 = c;

        if (d == a || d == b || d == c) {
            d = randy.nextInt(9);
        } else
            rand3 = d;

        // assigns random integers to their location in the array
        randArray[0] = rand0;
        randArray[1] = rand1;
        randArray[2] = rand2;
        randArray[3] = rand3;

        // prints and returns the array with its values
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randArray));
        return randArray;

    }

    // public static String[] compareGuess(String[] args, String str) {

    // return guess1;
    // }

}
```

Again, any guidance for a simpler way to do this would be appreciated (Im new, try to keep it to basic java if you can)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't handle the case where a repeated digit is generated twice.

`numberGenerator` doesn't need an input parameter and can be simplified significantly

Reading a String from the Console will simplify things.

The code below should be enough to get you over this hurdle

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create scanner object
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // give user the game rules
        System.out.println("The computer has chosen a unique 4 digit number (No digits in the number repeat)\n"
                        + "Each time you guess incorectly you will get a hint. You must guess the number correctly in 5 tries or fewer to win.\n");

        int[] solution = numberGenerator();
        // ask user for their guess
        System.out.println("Please enter your guess: ");

        // read the user input and store it in a string
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();

        int[] guess1 = new int[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            guess1[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)));
        }

        // this is some rough comparison code - you'll need to work on this

        if(solution[0] == guess1[0])
        {
            System.out.println("The first digit was correct!");
        }
        if(solution[1] == guess1[1])
        {
            System.out.println("The second digit was correct!");
        }
        if(solution[2] == guess1[2])
        {
            System.out.println("The third digit was correct!");
        }
        if(solution[3] == guess1[3])
        {
            System.out.println("The fourth digit was correct!");
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(guess1));

    }

    public static int[] numberGenerator() {

        // random number generator
        Random randy = new Random();

        // integer array with 4 positions (for each digit)
        int[] randArray = new int[4];

        // assigns a random value to temporary variable
        int a = randy.nextInt(9);
        int b = randy.nextInt(9);
        int c = randy.nextInt(9);
        int d = randy.nextInt(9);

        // tests to make sure there are no repeating digits in the number

        while (b == a) {
            b = randy.nextInt(9);
        }

        while (c == a || c == b) {
            c = randy.nextInt(9);
        }

        while (d == a || d == b || d == c) {
            d = randy.nextInt(9);
        }

        // assigns random integers to their location in the array
        randArray[0] = a;
        randArray[1] = b;
        randArray[2] = c;
        randArray[3] = d;

        // prints and returns the array with its values
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randArray));
        return randArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been stuck on this for longer than I care to admit

Comment: @JohnLapinski I found this interesting. I will make a real game based on this. Thanks for this idea! :D

Answer (score 1):

To fix your above code, Use `String` instead of `int`

```
String input = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Then on your `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    guess1[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)));
}
```